# Web Service behind nginx

Tags: java, json, rest, nginx

Given a snippet code of my rest service:

```
@POST
@Path("account")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ManagedAsync
public void save(final Account account, @Suspended final AsyncResponse response)
```

Now, I have this nginx configuation to pass request to it:

```
location ~ /rest/?(.*)$ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
   proxy_set_header    Host            $host:$server_port;
   proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   port_in_redirect    off;
}
```

My Problem:

If I post to /rest/account (nginx port 80) with a json body and content-type application/json, I get a 415 Unsupported Media Type error.  But if I post directly to port 8080 (to the ws app) then everything is fine -- I get 201 response.

It seems that nginx is not passing the correct content-type.  Is there anything I missed in its configuration?

Here's the nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Share full Nginx configuration first. Do you have included mime types conf?

Comment: Yes, mime type is included

Comment: Anatoly, I've included the nginx.conf above

Comment: does your backend support gzipped request? Try Nginx without *gzip on*.

Comment: No. That makes sense actually.  So I turned off (gzip off).  I still get the same problem. :(

Comment: Sorry *gzip on* is what you have between client and reverse-proxy, to disable gzip between Nginx and backend try another another directive: *proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87312/discussion-between-user241178-and-anatoly).